# Iterate over C# Iterator (IEnumerable) in Matlab

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I have a C# method that returns very large number of objects. This is to be consumed in Matlab.

```
namespace MyNameSpace{
    public static class MyClass{
        public static IEnumerable<MyDataObject> GetVeryLargeResponse(){
            while(CheckForSomeFunkyConditionThatsRarelyTrue()){
               yield return GetMyNextDataObject();
            }
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

In Matlab when I make a call

```
result = MyClass.GetVeryLargeResponse();
```

I would expect result to be of type `IEnumerable<MyDataObject>`, so as to be able to get the `Enumerator<MyDataObject>` by calling `result.GetEnumerator()`.

Where as I'm getting `result` which is of type `MyNameSpace.<GetVeryLargeResponse>d_3` with no `GetEnumerator()` method available. I do see one of `result`'s Super class being `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyClass>`.

Is there a way I can iterate over this in Matlab or even to 'cast' `result` to `IEnumerable<MyClass>` in Matlab.

p.s.

1. Converting to `Array` / `IList` etc is not feasible due to data volume
2. This is not duplicate of [How can I iterate over a C# IEnumerable in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6388688/277290), as that is dealing with `IQueryable` specifically.
3. I'm using Matlab 2010b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result *does* have a `GetEnumerator()` method - it's just may be implemented with explicit interface implementation.

If Matlab isn't willing to handle that, you could always write your own mapping type and an extension method to make things simpler:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static EnumerableWrapper<T> Wrap<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new EnumerableWrapper<T>(source);
    }
}

public class EnumerableWrapper<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> source;

    public EnumerableWrapper(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new EnumeratorWrapper<T>(source.GetEnumerator());
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class EnumeratorWrapper<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> source;

    public EnumeratorWrapper(IEnumerator<T> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public T Current { get { return source.Current; } }

    object IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return source.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        source.Reset();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        source.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Then try:

```
result = MyClass.GetVeryLargeResponse().Wrap();
```

It seems very odd for Matlab not so support this out of the box though...

Comment: Very smart solution - although it required a wrapper for Enumerator as well but it's spot on. I would still be very interested in knowing whats the solution in Matlab as C# code might not always be in our control.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser: Will add the wrapper for `IEnumerator<T>` for completeness. I'm afraid I've never used Matlab, so can't help there...

Comment: See my solution for how to do it in MATLAB.

Comment: Sorry for bringing up an old post, but wouldn't `AsEnumerable` accomplish what you're trying to do here, without you needing to create a wrapping type?

Comment: @Servy: Looking back after all these years, it's not clear to me why I've done *anything* here. It looks like the OP is looking at the execution-time type of the `IEnumerable<T>`, rather than the compile-time type. I'll edit a little...

Comment: @Servy: Oh, maybe this is a Matlab issue. I expect `AsEnumerable()` would just return the input reference, and as it's the execution-time type that's important here, that wouldn't help.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it's a Matlab issue, in fact you would get an error if you tried to call `AsEnumerable()`. I've posted the solution which uses explicit casts.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following example:

#### MyClass.cs

```
namespace MyNameSpace {
    public class Person {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClass {
        private static List<Person> people = new List<Person> {
            new Person {name = "name1", age=10},
            new Person {name = "name2", age=20},
            new Person {name = "name3", age=30},
            new Person {name = "name4", age=40},
            new Person {name = "name5", age=50}
        };

        public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople() {
            foreach (var p in people) {
                yield return p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### code.m

```
%# load my assembly
str = 'C:\path\to\MyNameSpace.dll';
NET.addAssembly(str);

obj = MyNameSpace.MyClass.GetPeople();   %# IEnumerable<Person>

%# call ToArray() extension method: this forces immediate query evaluation
NET.addAssembly('System.Core');          %# contains 'System.Linq' namespace
arr = NET.invokeGenericMethod('System.Linq.Enumerable', 'ToArray', ...
    {'MyNameSpace.Person'}, obj);

%# loop through results
for i=1:arr.Length
    fprintf('name=%s, age=%d\n', char(arr(i).name), int32(arr(i).age));
end
```

The code produces the output:

```
name=name1, age=10
name=name2, age=20
name=name3, age=30
name=name4, age=40
name=name5, age=50
```

As you can see, I did convert the returned object as an array `Person[]` (which I realize you were trying to avoid). The weird thing is if you if we look at the hierarchy of classes:

```
>> superclasses(obj)
Superclasses for class MyNameSpace.<GetPeople>d__0:
    System.Object
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyNameSpace*Person>
    System.Collections.IEnumerable
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<MyNameSpace*Person>
    System.IDisposable
    System.Collections.IEnumerator
    handle
```

you can see the `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<Person>`, but somehow the object doesn't seem to expose the inherited `GetEnumerator` method:

```
>> methods(obj,'-full')

Methods for class MyNameSpace.<GetPeople>d__0:

MyNameSpace.<GetPeople>d__0 obj <GetPeople>d__0(int32 scalar <>1__state)
logical scalar RetVal Equals(MyNameSpace.<GetPeople>d__0 this, System.Object obj)
int32 scalar RetVal GetHashCode(MyNameSpace.<GetPeople>d__0 this)
System.Type RetVal GetType(MyNameSpace.<GetPeople>d__0 this)
System.String RetVal ToString(MyNameSpace.<GetPeople>d__0 this)
event.listener L addlistener(handle sources, char vector eventname, function_handle scalar callback)  % Inherited from handle
event.proplistener L addlistener(handle sources, meta.property properties, char vector eventname, function_handle scalar callback)  % Inherited from handle
event.proplistener L addlistener(handle sources, string propertyname, char vector eventname, function_handle scalar callback)  % Inherited from handle
event.proplistener L addlistener(handle sources, cell propertynames, char vector eventname, function_handle scalar callback)  % Inherited from handle
delete(handle obj)  % Inherited from handle
logical TF eq(A, B)  % Inherited from handle
handle HM findobj(handle H, varargin)  % Inherited from handle
meta.property prop findprop(handle scalar object, string propname)  % Inherited from handle
logical TF ge(A, B)  % Inherited from handle
logical TF gt(A, B)  % Inherited from handle
logical validity isvalid(handle obj)  % Inherited from handle
logical TF le(A, B)  % Inherited from handle
logical TF lt(A, B)  % Inherited from handle
logical TF ne(A, B)  % Inherited from handle
notify(handle sources, string eventname)  % Inherited from handle
notify(handle sources, string eventname, event.EventData scalar eventdata)  % Inherited from handle
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what is causing the problem. As pointed out by @Jon Skeet, this _could_ be because of `IEnumerable<MyClass>` implemented by explicit interface implementation - that means we'll need to explicitly cast it to `IEnumerable<MyClass>` in Matlab. Not sure if we have a way to do that in Matlab.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser See my answer on how to use explicit casts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use explicit casts. First explicitly cast the IEnumerable instance:

```
result = MyClass.GetVeryLargeResponse();
resultEnumerable = NET.explicitCast(result,'System.Collections.IEnumerable');
```

Then get the enumerator:

```
resultEnumerator = resultEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
```

Then explicitly cast the enumerator:

```
resultEnumerator = NET.explicitCast(resultEnumerator, 'System.Collections.IEnumerator');
```

You can then iterate over the collection as desired:

```
while (resultEnumerator.MoveNext)
    resultEnumerator.Current
end
```