# How to translate C# syntax into Matlab?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I'm doing text-to-speech for part of a project, and Matlab has some functionality to pull in .NET assemblies, [but with very limited documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-net-from-matlab-an-overview.html). I'm having trouble calling some methods to change the voice. [Microsoft's SystemSpeech documentation implies that this should work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.selectvoice?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Speech_Synthesis_SpeechSynthesizer_SelectVoice_System_String_), but I get this error when I try:

```
objspeech.SelectVoice('Anna')
Message: Cannot set voice. No matching voice is installed or the voice was
disabled.
Source: System.Speech
HelpLink:
```

Here's a minimal working version of my code:

```
NET.addAssembly('System.Speech');
objspeech = System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer;
% objspeech.SelectVoice('Anna');
objspeech.Volume = 100;
SpeakAsync(objspeech, 'Hello World');
```

The only failure is with SelectVoice. I can't figure out how to change it. Running objspeech.GetInstalledVoices returns:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<System*Speech*Synthesis*InstalledVoice> with properties:

    Count: 2
```

Does anyone have any idea why SelectVoice wouldn't work?

Comment: `SelectVoice` would work.  You're calling `SelectVoiceByHints` instead.  Two different functions, that need different arguments.

Comment: I realize that. SelectVoice does not work as advertised - Microsoft says that in C# you can say SelectVoice("Anna") and it'll change the voice, but Matlab throws the same error as the one I added for SelectVoiceByHints when trying that.

Comment: The only error you show is for a call to `SelectVoiceByHints`.  The error is correct, you have passed the wrong parameters for `SelectVoiceByHints`.  `SelectVoice` accepts a string parameter, `SelectVoiceByHints` does not.  If you are getting an error trying to call `SelectVoice`, show that exact error.

Comment: I've updated the post with the SelectVoice error. What I really need help with is decypering what to pass to SelectVoice, like what the string should be. All I can get out of GetInstalledVoices is a 2 and I don't know how to translate that to the proper string.

Comment: Oh look, that's a *totally* different error message.  You know exactly why `SelectVoice` isn't working.  Your question really is about how to see the data returned from `GetInstalledVoices`.  Since that has type `IEnumerable<InstalledVoice>`, this will help you: [How can I work with IEnumerable<T> return types when working with the .NET Interface in MATLAB?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/232310-how-can-i-work-with-ienumerable-t-return-types-when-working-with-the-net-interface-in-matlab-r2015)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6614040/103167 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/6388688/103167   Unfortunately it looks like all the answers are a little messy.  You may want to write a utility function to do the `GetEnumerator()` dance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to finally get all the voices available and select a different one:

```
resultEnumerable = NET.explicitCast(result,'System.Collections.IEnumerable');
resultEnumerator = resultEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
resultEnumerator = NET.explicitCast(resultEnumerator, 'System.Collections.IEnumerator');
while (resultEnumerator.MoveNext)
    v1=resultEnumerator.Current;
    v1.VoiceInfo.Name
end

objspeech.SelectVoice(v1)
```

Here for my v1 was 'Microsoft Zira Desktop', so `objspeech.SelectVoice('Microsoft Zira Desktop')` worked. It's weird that in Windows settings I have Microsoft David, Mark, and Zira installed and working but only David and Zira are accessible through .NET.

Comment: What happened to your UX Stackoverflow account?

Comment: @Confused I got doxxed on Workplace SE and had to delete a lot of stuff.

Comment: Strewth. Sorry to hear that. That seems a bit... wrong.

Comment: I routinely get banned from Graphic Design SE, and sometimes from UX. They don't seem to like my way of expressing myself. It bothers me not at all. But doxxing... I don't know what to say to that. Very wrong.